# cpp:91: error: (-5) Type of input image should be CV_8UC3! in function fastNlMeansDenoisingColored

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I am having ubuntu 16.04.I have installed opencv2.4.9 and trying to run this code

```
import numpy as np

import cv2

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('/home/Picture/a.jpg')

dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img,None,10,10,7,21) 

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img)
p
lt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst)

plt.show()
```

But I am getting this error-

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Type of input image should be CV_8UC3!) in fastNlMeansDenoisingColored, file /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/photo/src/denoising.cpp, line 91
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/photo/src/denoising.cpp:91: error: (-5) Type of input image should be CV_8UC3! in function fastNlMeansDenoisingColored
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please print image shape and dtype

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply, but you have to convert the color from RGBA to RGB

Comment: my issue is resolved now. thanks